# Why some webpages works different or look strange in Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, webapps, websites

I have my computer for work with Ubuntu and another computer for personal stuff with Windows 10.
I have noticed that some pages loads extremely slow in my Ubuntu (Firefox or Chrome) than they do in my Windows.

For example, here in my contry there is a webpage where you can make transaction on e-commerce. In my Ubuntu I have to reload each page around 3 times to finish the transaction, but in Windows is very fluid and in 1 minute I have everything done.

I've read some questions but I'm not sure if they fit in my issue, cause some people talks about DNS and other one's talks about wireless drivers, so I don't know why is this happening?

Any help?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David Sorry I'm late mate.. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS